# I keep receiving this error "filename = sys.argv[1] IndexError: list index out of range". Any idea what the issue could be?

Tags: android, python

The code is supposed to display a animated image walking in front of a background. I received this code from my professor and I'm not sure what the issue is.

```
import sys, os, math

sys.path.append("./")
from livewires import games

import spriteUtils
from spriteUtils import *

filename = sys.argv[1]
x = int(sys.argv[2])
y = int(sys.argv[3])

##print(filename, "\t", x, "\t", y)

games.init(screen_width = 1152, screen_height = 864, fps = 50)

nebula_image = games.load_image(os.path.join('.', "race_track.jpg"), transparent = 0)
games.screen.background = nebula_image

anim_list = load_2d_sheets(x, y, filename)

anim = games.Animation(images = anim_list,
                        x = games.screen.width/2,
                        y = 2*games.screen.height/4,
                        n_repeats = 15,
                        repeat_interval = 10)
games.screen.add(anim)

games.screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you actually provide any command-line arguments to this program?

Answer (score 1):

I'd first print `sys.argv` so that you can see what it represents. For example:

```
$ ./myscript.py

>>> sys.argv
['/myscript.py']
>>> sys.argv[1]
IndexError
```

You probably want to pass additional command line arguments to your function like:

```
$ ./myscript.py firstvar secondvar
```

Answer (score 0):

`sys.argv[1]` is the first argument that you pass to your script, so you need to run your script like this:

```
python my_script.py arg1
```

`sys.argv[0]` is the name of your script itself, in this example `my_script.py`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this script requires 3 arguments, and you aren't giving it any. The syntax for calling it on the command line is `python script_name.py <file_name> <x> <y>` where `script_name.py` is the name of the actual program, `<file_name>` is a string, and `<x>` and `<y>` are integers.